# Is there a name for this C++ idiom in which a type vends a wrapper that expands its interface?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, naming-conventions, idioms

I have what is essentially a family of types that share a few common properties with each other. I could actually model this relationship fairly decently with C++ class inheritance. However, I also need to pass and store these objects all around my code, and keeping every instance as a polymorphic heap reference is a pain.

Here's the initial situation:

Enumeration type with values for all "subclasses":

```
enum class PhoneType {
    landline,
    cell
}
```

Type that's stored and passed around a *lot*:

```
class Phone {
public:
    static Phone landline(PhoneNumber number) {
        return Phone(PhoneType::landline, number);
    }
    static Phone cell(PhoneNumber number, optional<AppList> apps) {
        return Phone(PhoneType::cell, number, apps)
    }

    PhoneType type() { return _type; }
    PhoneNumber number() { return _number; }

private:
    PhoneType _type;
    PhoneNumber _number;
    optional<AppList> _apps;

    Phone(PhoneType type, PhoneNumber number) :
        _type(type), _number(number)
    {}
    Phone(PhoneType type, PhoneNumber number, optional<AppList> apps) :
        _type(type), _number(number), _apps(apps)
    {}
};
```

`PhoneType` enumerates different possible types of `Phone`s, which all have a `PhoneNumber` and may or may not have an `AppList`.

The issue is how to go about giving the outside world access to a phone's `AppList` once the caller is sure that it's dealing with a `cell` phone. Note that I don't want to simply vend the optional type, as this pushes a lot of error checking code into the calling function(s), which is not what I want (in the majority of cases, the caller knows the `PhoneType` of the `Phone` it's being passed without even having to check, so vending an `optional<>` is just unnecessary pain).

I could just add the extra accessors to the `Phone` class, and document that they throw/crash/etc. if the receiving `Phone` doesn't represent a `cell` phone. However, in the real code there are many more such attributes that would require more accessors, and each of these accessors is not at all clear about its preconditions when read at a call site.

Long story short, after a bit of consideration I ended up with this idiom:

Before the definition of `Phone`:

```
class CheckedPhoneRef {
public:
    CheckedPhoneRef() = delete;

    Phone& phone() const { return * _phone; }

protected:
    Phone* _phone;
    CheckedPhoneRef(Phone* phone) : _phone(phone) {}

private:
    friend class Phone;
};
class LandlineCheckedPhoneRef : public CheckedPhoneRef {
public:
    using CheckedPhoneRef::CheckedPhoneRef;
};
class CellCheckedPhoneRef : public CheckedPhoneRef {
public:
    using CheckedPhoneRef::CheckedPhoneRef;
    AppList apps() const; // accesses private member of referenced Phone
};
```

In `Phone`'s `public` section:

```
// (Comment above declarations in header):
// These assert that this Phone is of the correct PhoneType.
LandlineCheckedPhoneRef landline_ref() {
    assert(_type == PhoneType::landline);
    return LandlineCheckedPhoneRef(this);
}
CellCheckedPhoneRef cell_ref() {
    assert(_type == PhoneType::cell);
    return CellCheckedPhoneRef(this);
}
// (Plus const versions)
```

In `Phone`'s `private` section:

```
friend LandlineCheckedPhoneRef;
friend CellCheckedPhoneRef;
```

Now it is rather clear what assumptions are being made at any given call site: if I say `phone.cell_ref()` then I'm clearly asserting that this `phone` is a `cell` phone, e.g.,

```
void call(Phone& phone) {
    if (phone.type() == PhoneType::cell) {
        if (has_facetime(phone.cell_ref())) ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

bool has_facetime(CellCheckedPhoneRef cell_phone) {
    return cell_phone.apps() ...
}
```

(Dumb example, but you get the point. I know I could use a visitation pattern here, but the real code isn't quite like this.)

I like this design for what I'm doing. Problem is, I don't quite know what to name the vended wrapper types. I'm currently using the pattern of `LandlinePhoneLens`, `CellPhoneLens`, etc., but I know that "lens" already has other meaning in programming. Perhaps this isn't a big issue, but I wanted to ask to be sure I'm not missing a more established naming scheme.

Is there an established name for this pattern/idiom in which a type vends a wrapper that expands its interface?

Comment: _"Enumeration type with values for all "subclasses":_ That's a serious design flaw and you should rather use _dynamic_ or _static_ polymorphism instead.

Comment: Mixin is one term, I believe. Or composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent is unfortunately not fully clear to me.

At first, I thought that you'd just reinvented the **[decorator pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html)**, in which you add dynamically some responsibilities (accessor) to an existing object.

But looking more closely, I think that it all just looks like an **anti-pattern, a dependency mess, and a flawed design**:  eveytime that in the base class you need to be friend of derived class, you should have alarm bells starting to ring.

Instead of looking for a name, you'd better **engineer a cleaner design**.  Forget the enum, and go for an abstract `Phone` base class, with abstract functions corresponding to what every phone shall be able to do.  Then create two derived concrete classes:  `LandLine` and `CellPhone`, both inheriting from `Phone`.

Now you could consider that getting the list of apps is a common functionality of all kind of phones, and that a `LandLine` just returns an empty list.  All your code would then just use build in polymorphism to do the job in a proper an extensible way:

- If tomorrow, someone would invent a `TelepathyPhone`,  you'd just need to impelement the common functions required by the abstract interface, and all the using code would still work unchanged.
- In the worst case, if you'd really need to call a very specific class dependent function that was totally unknown in the common interface (e.g. `TelepathyPhone::displayBrainWavelength()`), you could go for an `if` using `dynamic_cast`.  At least you'd avoid to create a new enum everytime you invent a new derived class.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful :) I should stop avoiding the dynamic polymorphism that the language has built-in support for. My intent was that I wouldn't need to be passing pointers around so that my type would behave as a nice value, but TBH, as you've said it's likely far, far more trouble than it's worth.